# java String with delimiter

Tags: java

I want to split a String by delimiter "|" in Java and get the String array, here is my code:

```
String str = "123|sdf||";
String[] array = str.split("\\|");
```

I will get the array with 2 elements: `"123","sdf"`.
I expect the array have 4 elements: `"123","sdf","",""`;
is there any existing class I can use to do that? I also tried StringTokernizer, doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `split()` method has a secret, optional 2nd parameter!

```
String[] array = str.split("\\|", -1); // won't discard trailing empty elements
```

By default, `split()` (with one parameter) discards trailing empty elements from the result.

If the second parameter is provided, this default discarding behaviour is turned off and if positive limits the number of elements extracted (but will return less than this if less elements found), or if negative returns unlimited elements.

Read about it in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: Wow.  Learn something new about `split` every day.

Comment: @Makoto What else is there left to learn tomorrow?